# If an application links to a shared library, why is that library needed at compile-time?

Tags: gcc, dynamic, linker

I apologize ahead of time if my terminology is incorrect.

Let's say I have a shared library called `libVectorMath.so`.  In it are two interesting functions, `addVector()` and `subtractVector()`.  The two functions are prototyped in `vectorMath.h`.  I also have an executable called `testVectorMath`, which uses those two functions, and is dynamically linked to `libVectorMath.so`.

Generally speaking, to build `testVectorMath`, I need to build `libVectorMath.so` as well.  Why is this?  Is the header file `vectorMath.h` not sufficient to tell `testVectorMath` what symbols it should expect to find in `libVectorMath.so`?

In other words, can't `testVectorMath` have some instructions in it to say "look for a library called `libVectorMath.so` and then look for symbols named `addVector()` and `subtractVector()` within it"?

Comment: Have a look at the top answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159395/why-symbols-of-a-shared-library-are-not-resolved-at-link-time

Comment: How do you tell your executable *where* to find the functions declared in vectorMath.h?

Answer (score 1):

Read this [link](https://www.iecc.com/linker/linker09.html). Its tells about the same in a very good way!

An Excerpt from above is as follows:
All shared library schemes work essentially the same way. At link time, the linker searches through libraries as usual to find modules that resolve otherwise undefined external symbols. But rather than copying the contents of the module into the output file, the linker makes a note of what library the module came from, and puts a list of the libraries in the executable. When the program is loaded, startup code finds those libraries and maps them into the program's address space before the program starts, Figure 1. Standard operating system file mapping semantics automatically share pages that are mapped read-only or copy-on-write. The startup code that does the mapping may be in the operating system, the executable, in a special dynamic linker mapped into the process' address space, or some combination of the three.